# Can I press back button using selenium web driver of android emulator

Tags: android, selenium

Can I press back button of android emulator using selenium web driver?

Looking for help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Run the below command from my java class.
It helps me to press back button.

```
         Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /K cd " +"../libs/android-sdk-windows/platform-tools");
         Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /C adb shell input keyevent 4");
```

Hope it will help others

Answer (score 7):

I was using Selenium with Appium and Android emulator, succeeded with

```
webdriver.navigate().back();
```

Comment: +1 I can confirm this works with real android devices as well. My app has a "camera" button, which I need to click, then capture a photo, then hit the device back button. the above code works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

I've got the following assumtion:
as we have such mapping

```
**Emulated Device Key** -**Keyboard Key**:
Home -  HOME;
Menu (left softkey)  -  F2 or Page-up button;
Star (right softkey) -  Shift-F2 or Page Down;
Back  - ESC;
```

Try to emulate sending 'esc' key.

```
element.sendKeys(Keys.ESCAPE)
```

If you wanna handle some popup (e.g. alert or confirm dialog box) and do not have any possibility to localize element prolly this works:

```
Alert a = driver.switchTo().alert();
a.confirm(); // or dismiss() if you want to hit 'cancel'
```

Hope this helps you)

Comment: Thanks for your help but it does not solve my problem. But i manage to solve it using adb command